# "Thew X on her" vs "threw X onto her"?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-usage

What's the correct phrase? Example sentence:

> Susan threw on/onto Mary the wig she occasionally used for parties.

(I'm also open to other alternatives.)

Comment: Of related interest: *[On/To/Onto difference](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/122311/)*, *[The difference between the Onto and on to?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/140263/the-difference-between-the-onto-and-on-to)*, *[“Fell onto” x “Fell on” What's the difference?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/112951)*, and *[Should I use “on”, “into”, or “onto” in the following sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/120257/)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, we **throw something on**, that is, we put it *on ourselves* without giving much thought to the choice.  We don't throw the article of clothing onto another person.

Susan might have **tossed** her wig **to** Mary.